# Can a canvas be made click through?

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I have an absolutely positioned canvas and I would like it so that it doesn't interfere with clicking/dragging on the text that it is overtop of.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

This CSS added to your canvas element will let pointer events pass through to underlying elements:

```
pointer-events:none;
```

It is supported by the latest browsers.